# Github action: stored .env file content into github secrets and in pipeline want to put secret content in .env file

Tags: github, pipeline, github-actions, dotenv

I stored production .env file content into github secrets (in single variable), wants to create the .env file in pipeline and put the secret content into .env file.

Tried following methods

```
...
env:
  ENV_CONTENT: ${{ secrets.ENV_DEV }}
...
run: |
  touch .env
  echo $ENV_CONTENT
  echo $ENV_CONTENT >> .env
  cat .env



...
run: |
  echo ${{ secrets.ENV_DEV }} >> .env
  cat .env
...
```

Output: variable is env file is not getting defined.

```
> demo@1.0.0 deploy:dev /home/runner/work/lvld-api/lvld-api
> NODE_ENV=dev serverless deploy --stage dev

Serverless: Deprecation warning: Detected ".env" files. Note that Framework now supports loading variables from those files when "useDotenv: true" is set (and that will be the default from next major release)
            More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#LOAD_VARIABLES_FROM_ENV_FILES
Serverless: DOTENV: Loading environment variables from .env:
Serverless:      - STAGE
 
 Serverless Warning --------------------------------------
 
  A valid environment variable to satisfy the declaration 'env:REGION' could not be found.
 
 
 Serverless Warning --------------------------------------
```

Main.yml: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PK4SlyXkC7xRn_eM2SQO1rkWjoJaOYaZ/view?usp=sharing

GithubAction Log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YvBfdle1GpomJpyuqneQt0PK-OYShXZC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the problem here? Please provide the workflow output. At first glance, the problem may be related to the missing echo parameter quoting but it's only a guess without the putput.

Comment: @MarcinKłopotek env variable is not getting defined.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not enough to be able to help you. Please provide the full log output of the workflow (including echo and cat command output). What is the value of the `ENV_DEV` secret.

At first glance, the problem may be related to the missing echo parameter quoting but it's only a guess without the output. Have you tried to quote the echo parameter?

Comment: Please check, shared main.yml file and github action log. @MarcinKłopotek